# mutiple emails controller is not working how do i solve?

Tags: laravel

i have a problem this controller is not working how can i do? should send mutiple emails how do i solve?
I don't know how to handle it

```
function submit(Request $request) {

     $this->validate($request, [
          'email' => 'required|email',
          'file' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx'
      ]);

    $data = array(
        'name'  => $request->name,
        'cognome' => $request->cognome,
        'luogo'  => $request->luogo,
        'date' => $request->date,
        'telefono' => $request->telefono,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'citta' => $request->citta,
        'provincia' => $request->provincia,
        'studio' => $request->studio,
        'lingua' => $request->lingua,
        'livello' => $request->livello,
        'lingua2' => $request->lingua2,
        'livello2' => $request->livello2,
        'file' => $request->file,
        'agree' => $request->agree
    );

    Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) use ($request,$data){
        $message->to('luis@gmail.com', 'luis')->subject('Send mail ' . $request->name);
        $message->from($request->email, $request->name);
        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            $message->attach($request->file('file')->getRealPath(), array(
                'as'    => $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName(),
                'mime'  => $request->file('file')->getMimeType())
            );
        }
    });

    Session::flash('success', 'Mail spedita con sucesso');
}
```

I wish I could solve the problem
any advice? on how to do it?

Comment: `is not working` does not tell us what the problem is.  Describe what happens, what you expected, etc, what your logs show, how you call the method ... Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would like to be able to send multiple emails

Comment: hello I solved it like this
$ emails = ['myoneemail@esomething.com', 'myother@esomething.com', 'myother2@esomething.com']; use ($request,$data,$ emails)